# can sqldatareader variable run more than 1 time in the same scope?

Tags: c#

iam writing a simple POS code that takes the text from a textbox.text seek the needed values from sql and return needed values, each time the user press enter inside the txtbox the below code runs, but it is working only on the first attempt.

what is the problem here, is it the datareader?

```
    private void barcodeTxt_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {

                using (SqlCommand cmdgetscannedbarcode = new SqlCommand("", conn))

                {

                    conn.Open();

                    using (SqlDataReader reader1 = cmdgetscannedbarcode.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        
                        if (reader1.Read())
                        {

                           //do some code; 

                        }
                        else
                        {

                          //do some code; 
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: If it's not working on later attempts, what actually is happening? Where does it fail? What exception message do you see?

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn no exception is appearing it just go to else{}; i tried to reader1.close(); at the end but iam getting the same result

Comment: I will say that it's a breath of fresh air so see the `SqlClient` objects being managed correctly with `using`s. I will add that you might want to use async methods if you're running this on each keypress, but that's not related to the immediate issue.

Comment: If it's hitting the `else`, your query is returning no records.

Comment: @madreflection iam sure i am placing a correct value so it should read, my question is every time i press enter the same sqldatareader is being used, is this possible to use same datareader inside a loop? is there a way to dispose or close? i used reader.close(); reader.Dispose(); but it didnt solve my problem thx for the help

Comment: Probably should look at the URL I posted, it shows to use a `while` loop.

Comment: Doing a `while` loop on a result set is normal, but what user9938 pointed to won't enter the `while` loop if `if (reader1.Read())` skips to the `else` (the first call is returning `false` in either case. Show the loop you intend to use. I suspect you have something in mind that's different from how others might interpret that. Code tells all. As an aside, you don't need to close or dispose these objects because you have `using`s on them to do that for you. That's why I said "breath of fresh air": you weren't doing silly, pointless stuff like that in the code you posted.

Comment: Keep in mind that you don't need to test the `HasRows` property (shown in the linked article) unless you need to do something different when it wouldn't enter the `while` loop. The code there *does* have an `else` block on that, so it's needed there, but so many people unnecessarily test that property when it's sufficient to let the `while` loop iterate zero times.

Comment: Why is the SQL text empty in `new SqlCommand("", conn))` ?

Comment: no its not empty i just placed the main structure of my code.

Comment: You don't reuse the reader, you get a new one from `ExecuteReader` each time you call it. And you dispose it with `using` as you have correctly done. If your code is going into the `else` then there are no rows, I suggest you try it in SSMS